# CSRF Cookie of Django not available in Android PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, python, django, cordova

I am trying to access the csrftoken cookie sent by Django to the server. It works beautifully and I receive the csrftoken cookie in iOS PhoneGap (By calling xhr.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")  ),

However it doesn't work in Android. It only returns the sessionid cookie, and not the csrftoken cookie value.

I highly doubt that it is related to Django in any way, because Django shouldn't treat the request any differently, but I'm not totally sure.

I need the value of csrftoken to set the X-CSRF-Token request header needed for Ajax, so I need to extract the value from the server response in PhoneGap when logging in. It works perfectly in iOS, but not in Android.

Comment: ios and android should be the same. But I never try,I find in django docs,you can try `X-CSRFToken` instead of `X-CSRF-Token`,  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax